# create file json or text in angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular

i am trying to create a file .json or .text in angular and put it in path : /assets.

after searching for a while all result is to get data from file:

we can get data from file using this methode:

```
this.httpClient.get("assets/data.json").subscribe(data =>{
  console.log(data);
})
```

But how to post and create a new file data.json and put it in assets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers aren't allowed to simply write to files to the server. If that was possible, the Google homepage would be vandalised 30 times a second.

You need to write a web service (in the programming language of your choice, which could be JavaScript or TypeScript if you arrange to have a server on which you can use Node.js).

You *probably* want to write the data somewhere other than *assets* (which sounds like a directory that is part of the built Angular application and not a user data directory) and you *probably* should be using a database rather than using JSON file (databases are efficient and deal with simultaneous writes easily) — your web service can have another endpoint that reports the contents of the database as JSON.

Once you have a web service, then you can make a [POST](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request) or [PUT](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-put-request) request to the URL for it using `@angular/common/http` as described in [the Angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/http).